# jquery datatable search by default language in keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I would like the search bar of the the table to be implemented in English only, **even** if the user switched keyboard to a different language.

For example: the user typed `纽约` in the search text box
and it would still give the result for "New York".

Is there a definition I could set in it for this purpose?

```
$("#tbl").DataTable();
```

Comment: I made your question a little clearer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have the dataTables search bar interpret input from a different language as its English equivalent.

That is not supported natively by Datatables.

You would need to detect the entered language and translate using a lookup table for VERY simple words or an API that can detect the language of the input and translate it into English.

For example, Google Translate API can be used for this purpose, but it's a paid service.

Here is a simple version that shows what I mean

```js
const lookUp = {
  "纽约": "New York"
};

const translateToEnglish = (text, callback) => {
  // Implement translation logic here
  // This can be an AJAX call to a translation service
  // For demonstration, let's use a lookup table
  callback(lookUp(text) || text);
}

$(() => {
  const table = $('#example').DataTable();

  // Override the default search
  $('#your-input-id').keyup(function() {
    translateToEnglish(this.value, (translatedText) => {
      table.search(translatedText).draw();
    });
  });
});
```